# What are some open source alternatives to Firebase?

Tags: open-source, web-apps, web-development, saas

> ...the task you want to accomplish

- I want to build web and mobile applications.
- I don't want to maintain my own servers.

> ...your requirements for that task

- They must use reusable components. So I've settled on ReactJs.
- They must have a backend.
- I want a backend as a service so I don't have to maintain my own servers and infrastructure.
- **I want to avoid vendor lock.**

> ...what you already know about software available for this purpose

- Firebase. Can be expensive. [And in this case, unreliable.](https://startupsventurecapital.com/firebase-costs-increased-by-7-000-81dc0a27271d)
- I'm looking for alternatives to Firebase. Preferably one that is open source to best avoid vendor lock.
- Some possibilities I've seen include [Horizon](https://github.com/rethinkdb/horizon), [Backendless](https://backendless.com/backendless-5/), Digital Ocean, Linode and Spring Boot

Are there any open source alternatives to Firebase that can supply a backend as a service?

Comment: I'm not a dev – but I very much appreciate your question because of another argument agains Firebase: it's feeding the kraken (privacy issue). Wish you the best luck – and please ping me when you found something, so I can spread the word and convince other devs to switch!

Comment: I'm a very happy long term self-supporting Linode customer. I know they offer server management services as well, so I'd recommend them w/o reservation.  As for your back end, well, I do back end programming so I've never had that issue...

Answer (score 2):

I've started to collect [some alternatives here](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1896503#push), as this is a re-occuring issue at F-Droid (which does not permit Firebase or other proprietary components).

- [Gotify](https://github.com/gotify/server) is an open-source push notification server (you can explore its [Swagger API doc](https://gotify.net/api-docs))
- Server Sent Events (SSE) are used by some apps like Tutanota
- XMPP is used by several apps (of course including XMPP apps)
- Telegram and Signal use websockets in their FOSS environment
- MQTT is also used in some cases
- [OpenPush](https://f-droid.org/en/2020/02/03/openpush-talk.html) is an upcoming candidate (unfortunately not yet production-ready)

As I already wrote in my comment 2 years ago, I'm not a developer myself, so I cannot really say which is suitable for what and to which degree – but hopefully this gets you started.

Answer (score 1):

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21937223/any-self-hosted-firebase-alternatives#23121686) StackOverflow post may also provide some additional options, such as:

- meteor.js
- http://nobackend.org/
- https://deepstream.io/
- https://sapphire-db.com/start/main

One option that I felt was not mentioned in that post and deserves consideration is http://hood.ie/. I found it in a [medium post](https://medium.com/@brenda.clark/firebase-alternative-3-open-source-ways-to-follow-e45d9347bc8c) listing some open source firebase alternatives and it seemed like (and indeed was) the easier option to set up compared to https://appwrite.io/, which i also tried.